# Nokogiri LibXML version warning

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, libxml2

I just updated my Linux box from Debian Lenny to Debian Squeeze, and now when I use Nokogiri, I get a warning message:

> WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.6.32, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.8

I know I can eliminate the warning message by reinstalling Nokogiri, but for now I don't want to do that because the gem is in an NFS directory shared with machines that haven't been upgraded yet. I'll upgrade them all eventually, but for now I want to know: **does this warning indicate that Nokogiri will behave incorrectly on the Squeeze system, or may I safely ignore it for the time being?**

Comment: To avoid this warning, you can look at https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rdoc to see if it indicates the latest/most stable version of nokogiri that was built with the version of libxml you are using. If it does, you may want to use that version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work OK, it's just telling you there's a conflict between the versions.

The developers are interested in the users of the gem having a good experience, so they let us know when there are things going on with the system that we should know about.

It's better to have the visual noise and know what it's about, then to have the situation hidden completely and be surprised if something bad were to happen.

You might want to run some unit test code on that particular machine that exercises Nokogiri to confirm. There's always a possibility Nokogiri will try to use a call that changed or didn't exist in one of the versions of LibXML2, so you should confirm that.

If you want more information about possible issues it could have then the [Nokogiri-Talk](http://groups.google.com/group/nokogiri-talk) mail list is a good source. The developers monitor it and can answer any questions you have.

Answer (score 0):

In Mac OSX I had to pass the libraries dirs with:

```
gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/include --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/lib --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.26
```

Replace those dirs with your own after installing the development versions through apt or source.